# Are the real numbers separable under the K-topology?

Tags: general-topology, separable-spaces

My teacher used this example to describe separability $ \mathbb{R} $.
If there is a set $ A \subset \mathbb{R} $ and:
(i) A is dense in $ \mathbb{R} $.
(ii) A is countable.

He then chose $ \mathbb{Q} $ to show that indeed $ \mathbb{R} $ is separable by his definition under the usual topology. I then found that the complement topology on $ \mathbb{R} $ is separable and I believe that is also done by choosing $ \mathbb{Q} $. Now I feel like any topology on $ \mathbb{R} $ is separable. Is this always the case or does it fail under the K-topology?

K-topology: $\tau(\frac1n)=\{A\subset \mathbb{R}\ :\ \big(\exists N\in\mathbb{N} \big)\ \, \forall \big(n\in \mathbb{N} , n\ge N\big) \ \  \frac1n\in A\}\cup \{\emptyset\} $

Comment: What is the K-topology?

Comment: The discrete topology for any uncountable space is inseparable.

Comment: Your topology above is not Munkres $K$-topology, are you aware of that?

Comment: My teacher uses their own book, so I was guessing that they were the same because only the K-topology looked the most similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you define as the $K$-topology is not the usual $\mathbb{R}_K$ $K$-topology that Munkres defines in his book. The latter is the topology generated by all Euclidean open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ together with the $\mathbb{R} \setminus K$ where $K = \{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}^+\}$. It's his example of a Hausdorff non-regular space.

The Munkres $K$-topology *is* separable as $\mathbb{Q}$ is still dense in it.

The topology $\tau(\frac{1}{n})$ that you define is also separable as every non-empty open set intersects $K$ (as defined before), which is a countable set.

Comment: I guess as a follow-up question: Is the way to prove that a set is separable is to choose an open set in the topology such that the closure is the entire set? In my case the real numbers are the ones to pick. To me, it does not make sense that the rational numbers are the ones to pick for the finite complement topology.

Comment: @ChaseSariaslani not an open set; a **countable** set.

Comment: Thank you. Just realized that i said open.